# why is my function not working properly when i call for it?

Tags: c, function, while-loop, program-entry-point, fgets

i've written the code below

```
void readfile();

struct profile {
    char name[30];
    int age, phoneNo;
};

int main()
{
    FILE* fPtr;
    fPtr = fopen("profile.txt", "a");

    printf("\n\nPlease enter your details:");
    struct profile c;
    printf("\n\nEnter your name: ");
    gets(c.name);
    printf("\nEnter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &c.age);
    printf("\nEnter your phone number: ");
    scanf("%d", &c.phoneNo);

    fprintf(fPtr, "%s,%dy,%d#\n", c.name, c.age, c.phoneNo);

    fclose(fPtr);

    readfile();

    return 0;
}
```

the code above accepts data from the user and puts in into a text file called profile.txt, the stored records in the text file looks like this:

```
James Brown,37y,01123456789#
Mary Ann,45y,0123456749#
```

i called for the function `readfile();` in the main program, but the function doesn't work properly. the code of `readfile();` is as belows:

```
void readfile()
{
    char fName[15], line[30];

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("profile.txt", "r+");

    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(fName, sizeof(fName), stdin);

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
        fName[strcspn(fName, "\n")] = '\0';
        if (strstr(line, fName) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

in this function, i want to search for a name and print out the entire string containing the record. but when i execute my code, the code `fgets(fName, sizeof(fName), stdin);` seems to be ignored as it doesn't let me enter a name to search. rather, it just prints out **ALL** of the contents of the file, which defeats the purpose. when i call for this function using a `main()` with no other code, it works just fine, so I'm not sure why is it that when i have code in my `main()` that the function stops working as usual? i'd appreciate it if someone could point out how i can fix this problem in my code.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `return 0` for `void readfile()` function, remove `return 0`

I just posted an answer for your previous question, refer it.

[search string from file and store it in struct using c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64420740/search-string-from-file-and-store-it-in-struct-using-c/64422423#64422423)

Comment: hi, thank you for answering my previous question. :) for this question, i've removed the `return 0` in my void function, but it's still printing out all data. i think the problem lies in my main function.

Comment: In your main function you opened file in append mode `fPtr = fopen("profile.txt", "a");`,  if you are running your program multiple  times ( check `profile.txt` once), then same entries will be appended at the end of your file `profile.txt`, better use `fPtr = fopen("profile.txt", "w");`